# Icon of marker does not change the second time on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

I am building a web application to search for events using the backbone. In the home page, I have 10 images (that corresponds to the events) on right column and each of them have an id of event. In the left column have the markers that corresponds to the location of the images and each of the markers have an id of event too.

I have a function that detects an event mouseover of the image, and when this event occurs the icon of the marker that corresponds to the image is changed. And when I do a mouseover of another image the icon before is changed again to the icon default. 
But my problem is when I do the mouseover the same image twice, the icon of the marker is not changed. Here's a gif to better understand the issue: 
[the problem](http://rochinhaluis.tumblr.com/image/109586807495)

My code:

```
    ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(map, p, firstEntry){
            var that = this;
            that.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home'));
            ev.router.on("route", function(route, params) {
                that.deleteMarkers();
            });
            that.map = map; 
            that.firstEntry = firstEntry; 
            that.p = p; // valor da pagina
            that.icons = [];
            that.render(that.map, that.p, that.firstEntry);
        },


        local: function(map){
            ...
        },

        deleteMarkers: function(){
            ...
        },

        events: {
            'click #search' : 'searchKey',
            'click #maisFiltros' : 'maisFiltros',
            'mouseover .back' : 'overImagem'    
        },

      overImagem: function(ev){

            var target = $(ev.currentTarget);

            var id = $(target).data("id");
            this.icons.push(id);
            var last = this.icons.length-2;

            if(typeof this.icons[last] !== 'undefined'){
                if(this.icons[last] !== this.icons[last+1]){

                    for (var i = 0; i < this.marcadores.markers.length; i++) {
                        if(id == this.marcadores.markers[i].get('id')){
                            this.marcadores.markers[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
                        }
                    }

                    if(this.icons.length !== 1){
                        this.marcadores.markers[last].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');

                    }
                }
            }else{
                for (var i = 0; i < this.marcadores.markers.length; i++) {
                    if(id == this.marcadores.markers[i].get('id')){
                        this.marcadores.markers[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
                    }
                }
            }   
        },


    searchKey: function(){
        ...

    },

    render: function(map, p, firstEntry){
        var that = this;
        that.map = map;
        that.firstEntry = firstEntry;
        that.p = p;
        that.$el.html(that.template());
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.local(that.map);

            if(that.firstEntry != 0){
                that.marcadores = new ev.views.Markers(that.map,p);
                $("#lista").html(new ev.views.ListaEventos(that.p).el);
            }else{

                that.keyword = ev.keyword.get('key');
                that.secondSearch = new ev.views.Pesquisa(that.keyword, that.p, that.map);
                $("#lista").html(that.secondSearch.el);
            }
        }, 0);
        return that;
    }

});
```

View of markers:

```
ev.views.Markers = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(map,p){
        this.map = map;
        this.p = p;
        this.render(this.map,this.p);
    },


    apagar: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
            this.markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        this.markers = [];
    },


    render: function(map,p){
        var that = this;
        that.markers = [];
        var imagens = new ev.models.ImagemCollection();
        imagens.fetch({
            success: function(){
                var len = imagens.models.length;
                var startPos = (that.p - 1) * 10;
                var endPos = Math.min(startPos + 10 , len);
                var marcadores = imagens.models;
                for (var i = startPos; i < endPos; i++) {
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[i].get('latitude'),marcadores[i].get('longitude'));
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: that.map,
                        icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',
                        id: marcadores[i].get('id')
                    });
                    that.markers.push(marker);

                }
                return that;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid the code above is not sufficient to be able to help you.

Comment: I edited the code with more information, hope that helps.